# Display attribute using via() or viaTable() when there is multiple relations- YII2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have for models say, supplier-machine, supplier, supplier-to-part and parts. [image]

This is how these tables are related to each other.

In Supplier model the relation is defined as below to retrieve part_name of Part table keeping supplier-to-part as junction table.

```
public function getSupplierToParts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SupplierToPart::className(), ['supplier_id' => 'id']);
}


public function getParts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Part::className(), ['id' => 'part_id'])->viaTable('supplier_to_part', ['supplier_id' => 'id']);
}
```

In Detail view I use implode to display part_name

```
[
    'attribute'=>'Nature of business',
    'value' => implode(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($model->parts, 'id', 'part_name')),

    ],
```

My question is how do I display part_name in supplier-machine model instead of supplier model?? In this case I think supplier and supplier-to-part becomes like a two junction tables. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the parts through the supplier relation via `$model->supplier->parts`, assuming your relation to Supplier in your SupplierMachine model is `supplier`. You still have to account for the multiple parts though:

```
'value' => implode(",", 
    \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($model->supplier->parts, 'id', 'part_name')
),
```

Comment: Yes, this will display multiple records related to that supplier_id without any space or comma. How do I change it to include comma or space between multiple records?

Comment: BTW Thanks for your answer

Comment: If the first parameter in `implode` is a string, it will be used as the glue between the records. In the answer above I used a comma.

Comment: My mistake Thanks again.